# Mathematica Plot error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot Sin and Cos function in the same system.

But this code

```
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[t]}, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 6}]
```

lead to this error: `Plot::nonopt: "Options expected (instead of {t,0,5}) beyond position 2 in Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[t]},{x,0,5},{t,0,5}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to use the same variable x for all functions.

Comment: So, isn't there any way to plot Sin and Cos in the same system, on different domains? Maybe function `Plot` isn't the best choice.

Comment: Create two plots, assign both to variables and then call Show[] with these variables as parameters.

Comment: I used this and it works: `Show [Plot[Sin[u], {u, 0, 8}], Plot[Cos[k], {k, 0, 2}]]`

Answer (score 0):

`Show[Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,5}], Plot[Cos[t],{t,0,6}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)